# OleDB Select Statement

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, oledb

I have a search button in my program. What I want is every time I search I will type the `lastname` and when the `lastname` is equivalent to any `lastname` in the database, the `firstname` and the `lastname` of the person will be displayed in a `listbox` and whenever I click on the result in the `listbox`, the person's details will be displayed in the `textboxes`. The problem is when there are persons with same surname, their names are listed uniquely but when I click on the name, same details appear in the `textboxes`.

Please help.

Here's my code:

```
    connection.Open();
    OleDbCommand select = new OleDbCommand();
    select.Connection = connection;
    select.CommandText = "Select * From Accounts Where Lastname  = '" + searchtb.Text + "'";
    OleDbDataReader reader = select.ExecuteReader();
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        listBox1.Items.Add(reader[1].ToString() + "," + reader[2].ToString());
    }
    connection.Close();
```

Comment: One thing right of the top that is wrong with this. it's **wide-open** to a SQL injection attack. *Seriously* consider parameterizing that input.

Comment: Aside from being SQL-Injection prone. If you want to find people with just part of their lastnames you should use "Select * From Accounts Where Lastname  Like '" + searchtb.Text + "%'"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You dont have any error in this code, Your error can possibly be on your listbox_events.

Show your codes for the listbox part.

Answer (score 0):

```
 cFat_items2 = new OleDbDataAdapter("
      SELECT COUNT(Fat_Items.i_num) AS Count_i_num, Fat_Items.i_num, g.i_num 
      FROM Fat_Items INNER JOIN Fat_Items AS g ON Fat_Items.fat_nr = g.fat_nr 
      WHERE Fat_Items.i_num = '" + this.kLDataSet.Fat_Items.Rows[i].ItemArray[0].ToString() + "' 
      AND g.i_num = '" + this.kLDataSet.Fat_Items.Rows[j].ItemArray[0].ToString() + "' 
      GROUP BY Fat_Items.i_num, g.i_num HAVING COUNT(Fat_Items.i_num)>='" + Support + "'", con);

 cFat_items2.Fill(dFat_items2);
```